# MySQL CONCAT: how to add data at the end of string and delete data at the beginning if size exceeded?

Tags: php, mysql, concatenation

unfortunately I have not found anything yet, maybe anyone could help me or give me a hint?

I have a table called "users" and a field "last_login" where I want to store the login dates of the last let's say 30 logins. So, each time the user logs in successfully, the timestamp should be added at the end of the string, so it looks sth like this:

> logdindate1;logindate2;logindate3;...

..whereas logindates are timestamps with a certain size. However, if we reach logindate31, logindate1 should be deleted and logindate31 added at the end.

Is there any way to do that very easily within the MySQL query or do I have to check length with php? If yes, will I need a SELECT, then check the length, cut it and then a separate UPDATE? Or is there any better way to do it at all?

The query I have till now is (it does not check the length or cut anything):

```
<?php $query = "UPDATE user SET login_date = CONCAT(login_date,'".$logindate.";') WHERE id='".$user_id."';"; ?>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I would suggest creating a login-times table and then adding a record each time the user logs in - updating a single column like this is going to cause you more problems ( much like your seeing now ) - you can then query the login times and use limit - and remove old unrequired records as needed

Comment: thank you too, Manse UK. I got your ideas and you are very right for creating a new table with the login dates... like always, I wonder how I could have been so blind trying to realize this one solution without thinking outside the box... thank you for leading me on the right path!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a table login_history and insert the new login date there. Use a JOIN to retrieve the login dates of a user.

I strongly recommend you get a basic understanding of what's called "Database normalization"

Comment: OK, thank you very much ZombieHunter! I will definitely need that I know... so, thanks!

Comment: @Chris: I'm really happy you want to spend some time in learning proper DB design than just getting a quick and dirty solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

`$query = "UPDATE user SET login_date = RIGHT(CONCAT(login_date,'".$logindate.";', 256)) WHERE id='".$user_id."';";`

assuming that `256` is the length of the 30 login_dates you + the semicolons. See [RIGHT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right)

Comment: thx Darhazer for providing a solution for that! :) however, I think I will consider the suggestion from ManseUK and ZombieHunter and create a new table...